# Dynamic Components don't work in typescript in vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js

the Hello don't render in my HelloWorld page

HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
      <component :is="Hello"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import Hello from './Hello.vue'

@Component({
  components: {
  Hello
  }
  })
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  @Prop() private msg!: string;
}
</script>
```

[Vue warn in chrome Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACHl9.png)

Comment: because dynamic components require a variable from `data`, `props` or `computed`. Most likely `data`. So something like `data() { return { component: "Hello" } }`

Comment: It work.Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: @A.Lau you should put your comment as answer.

Comment: If I may add a question to this : how do you type your dynamic component ? Is it a `Vue` instance ?

Answer (score 1):

:is requires a variable. you have passed a string. Make that syntax change and it should work

```
<template>
  <div>
      <component is="Hello"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import Hello from './Hello.vue'

@Component({
  components: {
  Hello
  }
  })
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  @Prop() private msg!: string;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <component :is="Hello"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import Hello from './Hello.vue'

@Component({
  components: {Hello}
})
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  @Prop() private msg!: string;
  
  private get component(): VueClass<Hello> {
    return Hello;
  }
}
</script>
```

In addition to registering the `Hello` component, you need to return its instance from a computed property; you could probably assign it to a data property like `private component: VueClass<Hello> = Hello`, but the point is to make it dynamic, right, so I used the computed one here